# Node.js - convert webp to jpeg as a buffer (in memory)

Tags: node.js, jpeg, webp, converters

Do you know any way I can convert an `image/webp` buffer to `image/jpeg` buffer without the need to use the filesystem?

First I get the buffer with `request-promise` and then I would like to convert it and send it away in another HTTP call.

I found this package that works on files:
https://github.com/scionoftech/webp-converter

Then tried to find something useful in 
https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin
but was not successful.

Comment: Have you found the solution to this yet? I'm stuck too

Answer (score 2):

I found a very fast library for this: [sharp](https://github.com/lovell/sharp)

The syntax is really clear and easy too. To convert from a webp buffer to jpg buffer, you just do

```js
sharp(webpBuffer).jpeg().toBuffer();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [convert](https://imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) functionality in ImageMagick to do so, using it through the [GraphicsMagick NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gm). It accepts webp-compressed TIFFs which you can output as a jpg. When you install GraphicsMagick, make sure to also include ImageMagick and install it with a `--with-webp` flag so that webp is supported. When requiring the gm lib, make sure you also specify imageMagick:

```
 const gm = require('gm').subClass({imageMagick: true});
```

In the body of your promise you can call a function like this:

```
gm().command('convert').in('yourImage.jpg').in('yourImage.webp').toBuffer(function(err, buffer){
if(err)throw err
//...Do what you need with the buffer
});
```

Comment: How to do it with plain `Buffer`, without the need to use `yourImage.jpg` and `yourImage.webp` files?